# User Agent Stylesheet automatically setting h1 to bold?

Tags: html

The user agent stylesheet is automatically setting my h1 to bold, when I don't want it to be bold... How do I cancel it out?

```
h1 {
display: block;
font-size: 2em;
-webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
font-weight: bold;
```

}

Comment: `font-weight: normal`?

Answer (score 1):

define a style rule:

```
h1 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Why do people like throwing random !importants into their CSS for no reason?